# How to turn associative array into separate variables?

Tags: php

Here is an example:

### PHP:::

```
<?php

$tag = id3_get_tag( "path/to/example.mp3" );

print_r($tag);

?>
```

---

### response

```
Array

(

    [title] => DN-38416

    [artist] => Re:\Legion

    [album] => Reflections

    [year] => 2004

    [genre] => 19

)
```

---

### I want to set this like

```
$title => DN-38416

$artist => Re:\Legion

$album => Reflections
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to ask

Comment: What is `lestiner` supposed to be?

Comment: sorry . i was asking for array introduction . i was new then so i was trying to get some idea about arrays on php

Comment: You can use the infamous `extract()` function to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean to assign value to new variables, simply do it using the assignment operator `=` in PHP.

```
$title = $tag["title"];

$artist = $tag["artist"];

// ... and so on
```

Read more about [assignment operator in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php).

Comment: I don't know why the comments has been removed, or why this answer has 2 upvotes. Guys, this code has syntax errors, wth? Am I missing something?

Comment: I dont know either about the comments. Can you please point out the syntax errors? It will help me to improve my answer. :)